# Number of terms that does not contain single powers in a multivariable binomial expansion

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

Consider $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_p)^{r}$. I am looking for the number of terms of type $x_{i_1}^{\alpha_{1}}x_{i_2}^{\alpha_2}\dots x_{i_k}^{\alpha_k}$ in the expansion where $k$ is not fixed and $\alpha_{j}\geq 2$ for each $j\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably $k=p$, and you're counting terms with multiplicity? You could do that with inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: No restriction on k except it has to be less than p. Yes definitely, inclusion and exclusion is an option but I need a little bit more compact expression at the end.

Comment: $\sum a_j=r$ and $a_j\geq 2$. From here, I think u can proceed with stars and bars method to count number of ways.

Comment: @nyeowNyeow stars and bars won’t account for the fact that the same monomial arises from different multiplications. You would also need a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: Please clarify whether $k$ is fixed as part of the input, like $p$ and $r$, or you want a sum across all $k$.

Comment: @RobPratt Oh I was counting the number of distinct terms in the expansion. It equals to the number of way the sum can be done.

Comment: @nyeowNyeow yes the question is a bit ambiguous and it would be helpful for the OP to provide a clarifying example.

Comment: Rob, I did make an edit in regards to your comment. $k$ is not fixed. We are counting all monomials where each variable in the monomial has power at least 2.

Comment: Regarding the multiplicity, yes we are counting them too. Sorry about too many edits.

Answer (score 0):

Count words of length $r$ on alphabet $\{1,\dots,p\}$ in which no letter appears exactly once.  One way to do this is to apply the principle of inclusion-exclusion, where the $p$ properties to be avoided are that letter $j$ appears exactly once:
$$\sum_{i=0}^p (-1)^i \binom{p}{i}\binom{r}{i}i!(p-i)^{r-i}$$
Here, $i$ represents the number of properties that are not avoided, $\binom{p}{i}$  selects the $i$ properties, $\binom{r}{i}$ selects the positions of the $i$ letters that appear once, $i!$ permutes them, and $(p-i)^{r-i}$ populates the remaining $r-i$ positions in the word from among the remaining $p-i$ letters.

As a sanity check, the case $(p,r)=(2,4)$ yields $8$, as expected:
$$(x_1+x_2)^4 = \color{red}{1}x_1^4 + 4x_1^3 x_2 + \color{red}{6}x_1^2 x_2^2+ 4x_1 x_2^3+ \color{red}{1}x_2^4$$